# Java: create a new variable or do multiple times the same calculation?

Tags: java, performance

i have this piece of code:

```
// ...
if (result[1] / (abs ? res[0] : 1 > highest) {
    highest = result[1] / (abs ? res[0] : 1);
}
```

and I'm wondering if it's Worth enought to create a variable to avoid repeating the same calculation:

```
// ...
double temp = result[1] / (abs ? res[0] : 1;
if (temp > highest) highest = temp;
```

Which is the best soluton and also in general when is better to use the first piece of code and when the second one?

Comment: The second one. You don't want to repeat yourself.

Comment: The latter is arguably easier to read.  But you should really be using `Math.max` to make this logic even clearer.

Comment: For readability do add explaining variables, even if they do not improve performance. And reduce your use of trinary expressions. They tend to obfuscate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You eliminate duplicate calculation primarily to avoid repeating the same code; repeating the same computation for more optimal use of CPU comes a distant second.

Therefore, it is absolutely worth creating a temporary variable.

However, in this situation you can avoid creating it explicitly by using `Math.max`:

```
highest = Math.max(highest, result[1] / (abs ? res[0] : 1));
```

Here, the second parameter `b` of `max(double a, double b)` is used in place of a temporary variable. The value of the expression argument is set into the parameter variable at the call site, and used inside the `max` implementation to decide the return value, and ultimately the assignment.

Comment: Nice, but I liked your answer better when it was short and sweet, before you added the explanation after the code. It just obfuscates it in my opinion.

Comment: @user889742 Well, an ability to use `max` is a side effect of OP's particular example, not an inherent property of "should I use a temporary" question. Many readers who come to this Q&A through search engines would be disappointed, because the solution wouldn't apply to their problems. That's why I added the first paragraph, explaining the logic of why `temp` is a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

The second one is better:

1) It has better performance.

2) It adds to the readability of the code.

3) It's easier to debug when the calculation happens only once.

4) The first option is error prone since you might make a mistake when copying the calculation.